# changing chars in input

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int i= 0; i<inputAxiom.length(); i++)
{
  char c=inputAxiom.charAt(i);

  if (c == 'f' || c == 'h' || c == 'g')
  {
    if (rules[0].equals("f") || rules[0].equals("h")); 
    {
      inputAxiom = rules[1];
    }
```

Hello what I'm trying to do is get the user input from inputAxiom and for every f or h I want that part of the input to change

for example: if the inputAxiom = fff and the rules are f=f-h (which puts f at rules[0] and f-h at rules[1])

then it would change to f-hf-hf-h (changed each f to f-h)

Currently as soon as it finds f just changes to whole thing to f-h instead of f-h for every f

I think it has to do with

```
inputAxiom = rules[1];
```

but im not sure how to fix it

Comment: Strings are immutable. You will probably want to change the string to a char array with 'char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();' - then do whatever manipulation you need. If you foresee yourself substituting a single input character with more than one replacement character, you should probably convert that char[] to a collection such as a List.

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable example?  That is, the bare minimum of code to demonstrate the problem, but we can copy into our editor, compile, and run?

Comment: You are assigning inputAxiom reference to the String contained @ rules[1]....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You can not change a part of an existing String instance. What you can do is to replace it with a modified copy of the original string.

For example, to replace all `f` with `f-h`, you would do:

```
outputAxiom = inputAxiom.replaceAll("f", "h-f");
```

Another possibility of manipulating strings is the `StringBuilder` API (do not mistake it for `StringBuffer`, which it's not recommended anymore).

Answer (score 0):

You are currently changing the entire string:

```
inputAxiom = rules[1];
```

In order to change the specific characters, loop through your array like this:

```
var chars = inputAxiom.toCharArray();
for (int i= 0; i<inputAxiom.length(); i++)
{
  char c=inputAxiom.charAt(i);

  if (c == 'f' || c == 'h' || c == 'g')
  {
    if (rules[0].equals("f") || rules[0].equals("h")); 
    {
      chars[i] = rules[1];
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to insert that many characters, this will work::

```
inputAxiom = inputAxiom.replaceAll(rules[0], rules[2]).replaceAll(rules[1], rules[2]);
```